# Recursive Algorithm using iteration Method

Tags: algorithm

How Can we solve the below?
The following recursive algorithm for computing the sum of the first `n` squares:

```
Sum(n) = 12 + 22 + . . . + n2.
Algorithm: SUM(n)
if n = 1 return 1
else return SUM(n − 1) + n ∗ n
```

Write recurrence relation for above algorithm and solve it using Iteration Method.

Comment: Just iterating from 1 to n? your first formula is your answer.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place to post your homework for others to do... What have you tried so far? In what language are you programming the algorithm?

Comment: Recurrence relation is the expression you have, what is the question here? Recurrence relation is this: `F(n) = F(n-1) + n*n`. Also, instead of 12 + 22 + ... n2, you should probably write a `^`, `1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2`. It seems you already have all the bits you need for your answer, what is the question here?

Answer (score 0):

What about (Python):

```
def sumOfSquared(n)
    sum=0
    for i in range(n):
        sum+=(n+1)*(n+1)
    return sum
```

EDIT: Oh, right, as it has been mentioned in the comments, please don't post your homework on SO unless you get errors after trying it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by two way...

1. Sum of first n square is = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6;
   put the value of n .. solve the equation.. You will get the ans.
2. Another way to do it is to do it by loop...

   ```
   public int sum(int n)
   ```

   {

   ```
    int sum=0;

   for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
   ```

   {

   ```
    sum=sum+(i*i);

   }
    return sum;
   }
   ```